# Any good suggestion to animations with SWT/JFace

Tags: java, flash, swt, jface

I'm developing a desktop application using java + SWT/JFace, which I'm not very familiar. The program need to show some pictures presenting the program's progress like this.[image: moving diagram]

Sorry for my poor English, I'm not sure whether it's suitable to use the word "moving", actually I mean that the diagram is changing like Flash when an event occurs. I'm considering making some flash movies to play, but it seems difficult as I need to add third-party jars and I'm not good at flash. Is there any better way to doing work like this? I need your suggestion.

Thank you and sorry for my poor English again if I made some English mistakes that troubled you :)

Comment: The English word you'd want to search on is "animation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java2d and the awt-swt bridge or there is a framework called [Timing Framework](http://java.net/projects/timingframework) which works for swt and swing.

Answer (score 0):

probably you need a gif embeded in your window. java cannot paly any animations unless you have series pictures and play them one by one very soon.